# "Cloud" term is being sold and abused, what do I do?

Tags: cloud

I'm employed by an organization that is selling their products by claiming that it's in the "cloud." Their "cloud" is 2 servers with a few external USB hard drives "at the ready."

I told them that we conform to ZERO of the 5 characteristics of "cloud" as defined by the US Government.

I informed them of NIST pub 800-145... but they completely rejected it outright. They still think that "cloud" is only bullshit bingo. The CEO was pissed that I brought it up... and firmly believes his interpretation of "cloud" is the right one.

What do I do? I now fear for my job...

Comment: If you fear for your job, regardless of the particular issue, it's time to find a new one.

Comment: First I somewhat agree with the charaterization that the term *cloud* is 95% bullshit.  Aside from the cloud term, are you actively lieing to you customers?  Do you actually have an SLA or contract in place defining the use of cloud as something you are not delivering?  If you being asked to lie, then tell them your professional code of ethics prohibits that.  https://lopsa.org/CodeOfEthics Unfortunately yes, this may mean you lose your job.  In any case this is off-topic here, is probably going to get closed.

Comment: Cloud *is* bullshit bingo.  I'm with your CEO on this one.

Comment: If you're not selling to the government, their definition of "cloud" is meaningless. It's not a strictly defined term, and anyone customer simply accepting "it's in the cloud" as meaning "it's reliable and fault-tolerant" deserves whatever they get for not doing any due diligence.

Comment: The term "cloud" is not defined by one department of one government.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if I were you and I'd work in a company that's telling lies to customers, I'd get myself another job. Sooner or later this might blow up and then you'll be that person that worked for that "bad" company.

Step out while you can.

Comment: Run like the wind.  FTFY.